# Finding range of $a$

Tags: calculus

> If $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
>  |x-2|+a^2-9a-9, &\text{if }x<2\\
> 2x-3, &\text{if } x\geqslant2
> \end{cases}$$  has local minima at $x=2$, then range of $a$ is… ?

My failed Attempt:

Wrote 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 -x+a^2-9a-7, &\text{if }x<2\\
2x-3, &\text{if } x\geqslant2
\end{cases}$$

The problem here is that I don't know whether the function is continious is required or not for finding maxima and minima. Not that I could check it if it was

Then My next step would be differentiating

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 -1, &\text{if }x<2\\
2, &\text{if } x\geqslant2
\end{cases}$$

That means the function is decreasing before $x=2$ and then increasing. This is the best I could think for this question but it's not providing me any hint on how to proceed

Comment: A non-continuous function can also have (local) extrema.

Comment: I always get confused at non continious functions. I haven't seen examples of them so that's why I am always little confused when dealing with them

Comment: Should it be $|x-2|$ in the task? Otherwise I do not see how you get to $-x$ in the next step.

Comment: I miswrote that when double checked with my textbook. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A non-continuous function can also have the minimum at $x=2$

Here you want a local minimum at $x=2$ thus
$$
 |2-2|+a^2-9a-9\ge 2\cdot2-3
$$

$$
 a^2-9a-9\ge 1
$$
$$(a+1)(a-10)\ge 0$$

You get $$a\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[10,\infty)$$

You can look [here on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ihzzriphej) for the simulation

Comment: Can you tell me what did you do..... I am unable to. Understand it. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

There's no other way of doing this question except assuming it is continuous, otherwise why would they have given you the function broken like this at x=2?

So, put right hand limit and you get **4-3=1**.
Put x=2 for x<2 to get **$a^2$-9a-9**.

Since the function is continuous, both limits will be same, i.e. **1**
So, $$a^2-9a-9=1$$ $$ a^2-9a-10=0 $$ 
$$(a-10)(a+1)=0  $$
$$a=10$$ or $$a=-1$$

Comment: If I substitute a=-2 in the question then I get -x+15.This gives decreasing till 2 then increasing making x=2 minima I guess so I don't think x=-1 is the only solution. And the question also asks about range

Comment: a=10 and a=-1  are the 2 solutions.There are discrete values and not the range for a. And, given function needs to be decreasing and then increasing if it has to be continuous.

Comment: you solution is partially correct look at my solution hope you understand